# How to initialise useState with a dispatch

Tags: reactjs

In React functional components we can initialize useState with primitive values
(For eg false,0) . But I want to initialize useState with a dispatch action. For eg

useState(dispatch(‘FAV’,props))

doesn’t seems to work .

The action dispatch(‘FAV’,props) returns a boolean.

Any suggestions of how to initialize state in this way ?

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize your state, you call the `dispatch` function. Maybe this function returns boolean.

If you wanna use it later. Just simply pass the reference, don't call it.

Like that:

`const [myfn, setMyfn] = useState(dispatch)`

Use it later, with your argument: `myfn('FAV', props)`

Hope you understand.
Thank you

Comment: All the other components render the same content . So state is initialised  only once .

Comment: Please provide your source code. And clear that, what you actually need.

Comment: Is the question confusing ?

Comment: I think yes. I have answered that, what I understand.

Comment: Let me try once .

Comment: Not working Alam . setMyfn should dispatch not myfn

Comment: My requirement is that when the component renders myfn needs to initialzed  with the value returned by dispatch(‘FAV’,props) but not with a reference to dispatch

Comment: I am using myfn to conditionally render the content but not for dispatching action . setMyfn Is dispatching action in my code